# Proper way to add SASS to .NET 6 Blazor application?

Tags: css, sass, blazor, blazor-webassembly

So I've been searching a bit and it seems like using [Delegate.SassBuilder](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Delegate.SassBuilder) is a good way to add SASS to your Blazor project. It detects any .scss files and builds them into .css files in the same directory.

It works as expected, however, I'm looking for more customization regarding "code behind" files, but with CSS files instead (not sure what the right term is except "code behind but for css"). By default, your Blazor application will contain files such as this:

[image]

So you have a .razor file, and then you have a .razor.css file. In index.html, it adds `<link href="projectname.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />` automatically, which handles these styles.

However, if I rename that .css file to .scss and build the application, I end up with this result:

[image]

It works, but I have to build it first, then run the application. Quite annoying. What's also annoying is that the files are no longer nested. I would like to see something like this instead:

[image]

What would be even better, is that the .css file is hidden and I just have to deal with the .scss files. I honestly don't care what the .css file contains, as it has been minified and so on.

There must be a better way, but I can't really find it.

Comment: MainLayout.razor.css.scss is an easy way to get the file nesting to work. Its order reverse to what you want. But l think logically ok sort of: .razor needs the .css the .css needs the .scss

Comment: @BrianParker Yep, but `Delegate.SassBuilder` created the files seen in picture #2. I can't rename them, as that would just create a new file

Comment: Are you still using "Delegate.SassBuilder" as it has been [deprecated](https://github.com/delegateas/Delegate.SassBuilder). Maybe you found a good replacement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so it seems like I have two options:

A) Create a .filenesting.json file and have this as the content as the extensionToExtension (might need to be modified a bit):

```
"extensionToExtension": {
  "add": {
    ".razor.css": [ ".razor.scss" ],
    ".razor.css.map": [ ".razor.css" ],
    ".css": [ ".scss" ],
    ".razor.scss": [ ".razor" ],
    ".cs": [ ".cshtml", ".razor" ]
  }
}
```

B) Somehow get `<None Remove="**/*.razor.css" />` inside .csproj to work. As it is right now, the engine that handles CSS isolation does not look at excluded files.

For now I'll stick with option A, because that seems to work:

[image]

Comment: Did the .filenesting.json file require modification? I have tried creating rules as described above, but the css files are still not nesting properly.

Comment: @Dave I can't remember exactly. Sorry.